# Unix Shell File Descriptors

Tags: bash, unix, ksh, file-descriptor

I need to run a program called pg.sh.  It report stdout to output log. How do I save stdout and both stderr and stdout into 2 separate log files?

I searched and got the below code

```
(pg.sh 2>&1 1>&3 ) 3>&1 1>&2 | tee output.log) > final.log 2>&1
```

I understand 1 and 2 are File Descriptors pointing to stdout and stderr. 3 is another File Descriptor pointing to stdout.

The above code works fine, But I do not understand how this is being achieved. Could some one help me with the code written?

Comment: Parentheses are unbalanced in your code excerpt, could you please edit your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

starting from the outer redirection: `( .. ) 3>&1 1>&2` , the order is important:

- fd 3 is open for write as duplicate of 1 (stdout: here it's the pipe input)
- then fd 1 is crushed as duplicate of 2 (stderr) (or redirected to stderr)

the `|` input is then the fd 3, whereas the stderr is not captured by tee,

The nested redirection:

- fd 2 is redirected to stdout (which was redirected to outer stderr)
- fd 1 is redirected to fd 3 (which was redirected to outer stdout)

  as tee duplicates output logged, (the final redirection `>final.log 2>&1`, as the fd 2 is open after fd 1 they are both redirected to final.log)
  the file final.log will contain program stdout and stderr, but output.log only stdout.

Maybe it could be written easier, using `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3` which reverses stdout and stderr.

The following should do the same:

```
( pg.sh | tee output.log ) >final.log 2>&1
```

The following writes program stdout to output.log stderr to error.log and both to final.log.

```
( ( pg.sh | tee output.log ) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee error.log ) >final.log 2>&1
```